# AWS Lambda: Error observed in cloudwatch metric for SampleCount statistics for lambda errors, no logs logged in cloudwatch logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to debug error observed in cloud-watch error metric graph.

[image: cloud-watch error metric]

This error is observed on every invocation.
I have also setup cloud-watch alarm for this metric, but alarm was triggered only on 1st execution.

Lambda function is successfully executed and adding files in s3-bucket as intended. Test results are also shown as Succeeded in lambda tests. All executions logs are available except this particular error logs.

I checked cloud-watch event trigger logs and had seen nothing that could have caused this error.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. After a lot of checking, what I found is that if we use 'Sample Count' as the Statistic, then it shows the count of samples they considered for error. If you change the Statistic to another metric, like sum or average, then it will be zero (If there were no real errors).
I changed my alarms to use Sum as the statistic, and now it's working well.

I checked AWS documentation, but I didn't fully understand why the sample count shows all the samples it considered; it should be the actual number of errors that happened.